# Как на PHP в Ubuntu запустить python файл?

Tags: php, python

На удаленном сервере с Ubuntu находится php сайт. Мне нужно через php запустить python файл, но никак это не получается. Хотя на локальном сервере на Windows все отлично работает. Из-за чего это может быть? Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.
Вот php код:

```
<?php
    $comand = escapeshellcmd('python3 /var/www/html/synthesizer/test.py');
    $py = system($comand);
    echo $py;
?>
```

Python код:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello world')

for x in range(1,50000000):
    pass

print('sdasd')
```

Я использовал и другие команды для запуска на PHP python файла, но все равно ничего не работает.
exec(), shell_exec()

Comment: на сервере питон то стоит?

Comment: Да, конечно. Когда напрямую запускаю этот     pyhon файл, то все работает.

Comment: На локальном сервере Ubuntu тоже не запускается через php. А на Windows все работает

Comment: Версия Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: а покажите-ка `ls -l`

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142 ноя 30 10:15 index.php

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 ноя 30 10:16 test.py

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11 ноя 29 16:33 test.txt